# What happens to a one way WCF service which opens some threads & leaves them to work on their own

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have a one way WCF service which calls a method which opens 4 threads & returns back.
leaving the threads to perform some work.

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "CalcinBackGround")]
public void CalcinBackGround(string somedata)
{
    CallAllWork(somedata);
    DoSomeOtherWork();
}

string CallAllWork(string somedata)
{
    Exception exc1 = null, exc2 = null, exc3 = null, exc4 = null;

    Thread thr1 = new Thread(() => SafeExecute(() => DoSomeWork1(new object[] {somedata}), out exc1));
    Thread thr2 = new Thread(() => SafeExecute(() => DoSomeWork2(new object[] {somedata}), out exc2));
    Thread thr3 = new Thread(() => SafeExecute(() => DoSomeWork3(new object[] {somedata}), out exc3));
    Thread thr4 = new Thread(() => SafeExecute(() => DoSomeWork4(new object[] {somedata}), out exc4));

    thr1.Start();
    thr2.Start();
    thr3.Start();
    thr4.Start();

    return "Done";
}

private static void SafeExecute(Action test, out Exception exception)
{
    exception = null;

    try
    {
        test();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exception = ex;
    }
}
```

As can be seen from the code , 
I have just started the threads & returned from the method to perform some other operations.

Is it a good way to leave them open & not wait for them to finish (since it is working in a one way service.) or is there any other way to make this happen ?

**For Clarity :** I am not at all concerned with the work which is being done in the threads so waiting for them to 
 finish makes no sense to me.

Comment: If it's a one-way service anyway, why not wait for them to finish? Nobody will notice.

Comment: Waiting for it to finish would mean that i cannot carry on other tasks which have no dependency on the outcome. (DoSomeOtherWork)

Comment: Sure you can. Just wait for the threads *after* you did all your other work.

Comment: Are you hosting in IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good way to leave them open & not wait for them to finish
>   (since it is working in a one way service.) or is there any other way
>   to make this happen ?

Firstly, a `IsOneWay=true` on your service just means that the service will not return a response (other than HTTP 200 code). It doesn't provide any guarantee that the service call will be successfully handled.

So whether the service is one-way or not is irrelevant, leaving threads running in a process container on some machine to which you have lost any visibility is only acceptable if the execution completion or failure of those threads is unimportant to you.

If this is the case (failure is not important), and/or you have some other mechanism for monitoring the progress of these threads and recovering from any failure, then your approach is fine.

However, my suspicion would be that this is not the case and you need these threads to finish processing and also to know the outcome. If this is the case then depending on how the service is hosted is quite important.

If you host in IIS, then you cannot rely on the appDomain hanging around for enough time to complete the running of your threads. [IIS can and will](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) unload your entire application from memory if it feels like it, and this will obviously kill all your threads.

If you host in a windows service, this is slightly more stable as a hosting container, as windows services tend to remain available unless they suffer some kind of unhandled exception or crash in some other way. In this instance, you would need to code to handle this kind of event.

In either case, if you use a one-way call you will lose visibility of the process which is running your threads.

My recommended approach would be to use a [backgrounder](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Background) to manage your tasks.

One which I have used, called [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/), allows you to run background tasks in a durable manner and provides a dashboard so you can see progress and deal with failures. I would certainly recommend this, though it has a dependency on SQL server.